# Group isomorphism of the nonzero real numbers

Tags: abstract-algebra

$G$ is set $\{x \in \mathbb{R} : x \neq -1\}$ with group operation $x\circ y=x+y+xy$.

Show that $f(x)=x-1$  is an isomorphism from the multiplicative group $\mathbb{R}^*$ to $G$.

Comment: Does $R$ here mean the real numbers?  I'll format the question assuming this is the case.

Comment: The answer of lhf shows that $g(x)=x+1$ and its inverse $f(x)=x-1$ are group isomorphisms.

Comment: in that question is set f(x)=x+1. but in here is x-1. but they got same answer, i still dont know how to solve it, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

To show $f$ is a homomorphism, you must show that:

$f(xy) = f(x) \circ f(y)$, that is:

$xy - 1 = (x - 1) \circ (y - 1) = (x - 1) + (y - 1) + (x -1)(y-1)$

$= x - 1 + y - 1 + xy - x - y + 1 = xy + (x - x) + (y - y) + 1 - 1 - 1$

but this is clearly true.

Now $f$ is a bijection between $\Bbb R$ and itself, and $f$ maps $0$ to $-1$, showing $f$ is thus also a bijection from $\Bbb R^{\ast} = \Bbb R\setminus\{0\}$ to $\Bbb R\setminus \{-1\}$, which is the underlying set of $G$.